# how to give namespace access to a user in gke?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, namespaces, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a google kubernetes engine cluster with multiple namespaces. Different applications are deployed on each of these namespaces. Is it possible to give a user complete access to a single namespace only?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the user to the cluster-admin role using a Rolebinding in your namespace of choice. As specified in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles), cluster-admin:

> Allows super-user access to perform any action on any resource. When
>   used in a ClusterRoleBinding, it gives full control over every
>   resource in the cluster and in all namespaces. When used in a
>   RoleBinding, it gives full control over every resource in the
>   rolebinding's namespace, including the namespace itself.

For example:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: yournamespace
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: example-user
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kubernetes has a built-in RBAC system that integrates with Cloud IAM so that you can control access to individual clusters and namespaces for GCP users.

1. Create a Kubernetes `Role`

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: YOUR_NAMESPACE
  name: ROLE_NAME
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

2. Create a Kubernetes `RoleBinding`

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ROLE_NAME-binding
  namespace: YOUR_NAMESPACE
subjects:
# GCP user account
- kind: User
  name: janedoe@example.com
```

Reference

- [Kubernetes Role-based access control](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control)

Comment: Well. Thanks. Half a way there. what should be the role granted to the user under IAM, so that the user can have full access to one namespace (using role and rolebinding as you mentioned) and should not be able to list pods in other namespaces?